# Find IP address of host on which VM is running

Tags: networking, ip-address

I would like to find IP address of host on which VM is running. How can I find that?

For example,
There are 2 machine. Machine A & Machine B.
Machine A is running on Windows OS,
Machine B is running on Ubuntu in virtuallization environment inside Machine A.

How can I get IP address of Machine A from Machine B?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes in Vmware environment detects the ip addresses which you can find under summary tab. Otherwise you will need to login to the virtual machine and find the ip.

Comment: So is it impossible to get IP address of host programmatically?

Comment: if you know the name of the virtual machine you can try pyvmomi its python api that connects to the vcenter and can get information. You can also do the same with powershell.
pyvmomi example :
http://vthinkbeyondvm.com/how-did-i-get-started-with-the-vsphere-python-sdk-pyvmomi-on-ubuntu-distro/